# Firebase not recognized in AppDelegate of my Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase

I wrote a Fluter plugin which shows native screens and in some I use Firebase which i do initialize in the ios/Classes/AppDelegate.swift file.
The problem is that when I run the example app I get `No such module 'Firebase'` on its import.
I did implement auth, analytics and crashlytics in the plugin .podspec file as:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'my_native_screens_plugin'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Analytics', '10.9.0' 
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Auth', '10.9.0'
  s.dependency 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '10.9.0'
  s.dependency 'MBProgressHUD', '1.2.0'
  s.dependency 'PanModal', '1.2.7'
  s.dependency 'TouchDraw', '2.1.2'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/TextFields', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/TextFields+Theming', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Cards', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/BottomNavigation', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Chips', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Chips+Theming', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Tabs+TabBarView', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'MaterialComponents/Buttons', '122.0.1'
  s.dependency 'YPImagePicker', '5.2.2'
  s.dependency 'SwiftRichString', '3.7.2'
  s.dependency 'IGListKit', '4.0.0'
  s.dependency 'SDWebImage', '5.13.1'
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'kotlin-mpp/kotlin-mpp/build/cocoapods/framework/kotlin_mpp.framework'




  s.platform = :ios, '14.0'



  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

I did try to add `s.dependency 'Firebase/CoreOnly', '10.9.0'`  as well as I saw it in the official Firebase packages, but it didn't make any difference..
When installing the pods dough it all seem to run as it should:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (10.9.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.19.0)
Installing FirebaseSessions (10.19.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (3.2.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (10.9.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.3.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.12.0)
Installing IGListDiffKit (4.0.0)
Installing IGListKit (4.0.0)
Installing MBProgressHUD (1.2.0)
Installing MDFInternationalization (3.0.0)
Installing MDFTextAccessibility (2.0.1)
Installing MaterialComponents (122.0.1)
Installing PanModal (1.2.7)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.3.1)
Installing PromisesSwift (2.3.1)
Installing PryntTrimmerView (4.0.2)
Installing SDWebImage (5.13.1)
Installing SteviaLayout (5.1.2)
Installing SwiftRichString (3.7.2)
Installing TouchDraw (2.1.2)
Installing YPImagePicker (5.2.2)
Installing integration_test (0.0.1)
Installing my_native_screens_plugin (0.0.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 33 total pods installed.
```

Can you spot if I'm doing anything wrong in the .podspec file or should I look for the cause elsewhere?
Many thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit o try and error, I tried using `s.dependency 'Firebase/CoreOnly', '10.9.0'`  instead and it doesn't throw the error anymore. Still I have to find out why in native iOS app Firebase pod doesn't fail while in a Flutter plugin does. This might be just a momentary workaround but so far so good.